# Ajax call 500 server error for Django - Azure

Tags: http, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment, azure-authentication

I have an azure deployed django web app in which it shows instagram embedded pages one by one when I click next.

**Issue:-**

When I switch on the Azure Active Directory authentication ON, it loads the first instagram embedded link but on click on next button which should load the next embedded page, it shows a http 500 error message on console and doesn't load the page.

And if I switch off AD authentication and set to anonymous access, the pages load without any issue on the next click.

What is the issue and how can be able to load them with my authentication settings on?

**EDIT**

I had come to a conclusion before that instagram pages were the problem behind the pages not able to load but it seems that's not the issue.

The problem is with the URL I am calling while clicking the next button.
With authentication, the app doesn't direct to next page but without any authentication, it successfully goes to next page.

Refer the code below where I am making the call:-

```
$("#button-next").click(function(e){
    var fin = '';
    $.ajax({
        url: 'mywebsitename.azurewebsites.net/next_details/',
        method: 'GET',
        data: {'link': window.location.href},
        success: function(response) {
            if (response.data != 'no links') {
              $.each(response['data'], function(index, value){
                fin += "//pass"
             });
             $('append-iframes').html(fin);
             window.location.href = '*' + response.name + '/?type=' + response.check_type;
            }
        }
        })
        })
```

**EDIT - 2**

//Next_details function

```
@csrf_exempt
https://myappname.azurewebsites.net
def next_details(request):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    check_type = ''.join(findall('type=(.*)', request.POST.get('link', '')))
    data_list = []
    if check_type:
        present_link = request.POST.get('link', '').split('/')[-2]
        if check_type == 'all':
            data = urlopen('https://myappname.azurewebsites.net/get_detailed/').read()
        else:
            data = urlopen('https://myappname.azurewebsites.net/get_detailed_%s/' % check_type).read()
    else:
        check_type= 'all'
        present_link = request.POST.get('link', '').split('/')[-1]
        data = urlopen('https://myappname.azurewebsites.net/get_detailed/').read()
    data_json = json.loads(data)
    qual_data = [dt['id'] for dt in data_json['qual_data'] if dt['name'] == present_link]
    if qual_data:
        present_id = qual_data[0]
        next_acc = [dt['name'] for dt in data_json['qual_data'] if dt['id'] == present_id + 1]
        acc_name = next_acc[0]
        links = Radarly.objects.filter(screen_name=acc_name, status='Active')
        if links:
            for link in links:
                data_list.append({'perma_link': link.permalink, 'name': acc_name})
            data = json.dumps({'data': data_list, 'check_type': check_type})
            return HttpResponse(data, content_type ="application/json")
        else:
            new_data = json.dumps({'data': 'no links'})
            return HttpResponse(new_data, content_type ="application/json")
```

Also below is a screenshot of the error which shows on the DOM.
[image]

Comment: Do you generate the embedded pages codes by accessing the instagram site or write by yourself?  You just add these codes in your html page? If possible, please post some relevant codes about your page.

Comment: @BrandoZhang-MSFT - There is a bit of a change in the issue I have. Please have a look.

Comment: @Ro_nair According to the 500 Internal Server Error and the url of ajax call, I think your issue was caused by the code logic of Django backend. Could you post more details about the code for the url path `next_details` and `details` for helping resolve it?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT - Sure! I have posted my code function "next_details" which is present in my views module in Django. Please have a look.

Comment: @Ro_nair Any backend logs for this ajax calling?

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT - The problem is this function is not at all getting called when we activate the azure authentication for active directory. If we don't use authentication, then it works smoothly.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT - Hey Peter, it would be really helpful if you could provide more insights.